# Mixed conditionals?? (1st and 3rd?)

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, conditional-constructions, content-clauses

I came across these sentences and I couldn't determine which type of conditional they were.

> 1. If you didn't go to the last meeting, you won't be allowed in the
>    next one.
> 2. If you didn't like that car, you shouldn't have bought it.

Especially the second sentence I don't get how a past real condition(past simple) with an unreal past result(present perfect) works

The first seems to me like a first conditional but it's not. I hope you can explain to me what these are.

Answer (score 1):

Both the conditionals have a past tense in the protasis, which is usually a sign of an *irrealis* or *counterfactual* conditional. But in both these instances, it is actually a *realis* conditional in the past.

The first says that if it is *actually*, now, a fact that you didn't go to the last meeting, then you will not be allowed to the next one: it is not a hypothetical.

Similarly, the second one is not a hypothetical ("what would have happened if you didn't like the car") but says that if in fact you didn't like the car, then it was not a good idea ("shouldn't") for you to buy it.

I don't know with any clarity what "first" and "third" conditionals are - I know a fair bit of linguistics, but I've never been involved in TESOL.

If a first conditional is defined by having a non-past verb, then those are not first conditionals. If a first conditional is defined by being *realis* rather than *irrealis*, then those are first conditionals, despite their past tense verbs.

And if what you have been taught is that a past tense in a conditional implies that it is *irrealis*, then these are counter-examples that show that you have been taught an oversimplification.

Comment: Today I learned the word "protasis".  :-)

Comment: The 0-1-2-3 model of conditionals is... kind of bad, really.